# jQuery hide element when click in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a hidden div which will be shown on a button click and hide when i click every where else in page.

Now the problem is here:
Inside my div I have datepickers whenever I click on next/prev or select date,div slides up. How can I prevent that?

The code is here:

```
$(document).click(function(evt) {
    if(evt.target.id!='btn' )
         if($('#div').is(':visible')) {
              $('#div').slideUp();
          }
 });

$("#div").click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation(); 
                return false;     
            });

 $('#btn').click(function () {
                if($('#div').is(':visible')) {
                    $('#div').slideUp();
                }
                else{
                   //initialize controls
                    $('#div').slideDown();
                }

            });
```

**Update:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh_hasanzade/6n75zyfo/1/) added.**

Comment: could you please provide your html document stucture.

Comment: and if possible fiddle too

Comment: thank you.I have added jsfiddle

Comment: Please check the answer I have added..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check my js [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/xpj274pd/)

I have added date picker id `#ui-datepicker-div"` for stop propagation, and it's worked.

```
$(document).click(function(evt) {
    if(evt.target.id!='btn' )
         if($('#div').is(':visible')) {
              $('#div').slideUp();
         }
 });
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$("#div, #ui-datepicker-div").click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation(); 
                return false;     
            });

 $('#btn').click(function () {
                if($('#div').is(':visible')) {
                    $('#div').slideUp();
                }
                else{
                   //initialize controls
                    $('#div').slideDown();
                }

            });
```

Comment: didn't work.plz take a look at jsfiddle I just added

Comment: See the added fiddle for same http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/xpj274pd/  this working fine for me

Comment: @shaghayeghhassanzadeh also updated your fiddle check here http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/6n75zyfo/3/

Answer (score 0):

you have to slideUp your required div if you click anywhere in your document body except your button 'btn', your div itself AND div children:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
 if ( e.target.id != 'btn' && e.target.id != 'div' && !$('#div').find(e.target).length) {
       if($('#div').is(':visible')) {
              $('#div').slideUp();
          }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `document.ready` you made mistake in `if` block, I modified it as

```
 if(evt.target.id!='btn' ){
             if($('#div').is(':visible')) {
                  $('#div').slideDown();
              }
}
```

Also try to avoid using id as 'btn' as it this id or class will make confusion if you use more css in your design

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of the same problem. Use some common class for those elements that wouldn't hide your div. Hope it will help you:

HTML :

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="container" style="display:none">
    <input type="date" class="prevent-click">
</div>
<button onclick="display()" class="prevent-click">click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS :

```
var display = function () {
$("#container").toggle();
   $("body").off("click").on("click", function (event) {
          if ($(event.target).hasClass("prevent-click")) {
                return;
           }
           $("#container").hide();
    });
  }
```